# Getting profile image in iOS via STTwitter

Tags: objective-c, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, ios7, sttwitter

I am using the the STTwitter API to make an App only twitter Feed. I have successfully output the tweet to the table cell, but now I'm attempting to connect user profile images and I am running in to some problems. I tried implementing the code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996676/how-to-get-twitter-profile-pic-using-api-1-1-from-ios), but I was getting an error stating "No known class method for selector 'imageWithContentsOfURL:'" so I fixed the problem by replacing UIImage with CIImage. However, now my app is crashing because I'm trying to output a CIImage to an UIImageView. My code and errors are as follows:

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSString* boldFontName = @"Avenir-Black";

    [self styleNavigationBarWithFontName:boldFontName];

    self.title = @"Twitter Feed";

    self.feedTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.feedTableView.delegate = self;

    self.feedTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.feedTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9 alpha:0.6];

    //self.profileImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"profile.jpg", @"profile-1.jpg", @"profile-2.jpg", @"profile-3.jpg", nil];

    STTwitterAPI *twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIAppOnlyWithConsumerKey:@"stuff"
                                                            consumerSecret:@"stuff"];

    [twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {

        [twitter getUserTimelineWithScreenName:@"RileyVLloyd"
                                  successBlock:^(NSArray *statuses) {
                                      self.twitterDataSource = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:statuses];

                                      for (int i=1; i <= _twitterDataSource.count; i++) {
                                      NSLog(@"%d", i);
                                      NSDictionary *tweetDictionary = self.twitterDataSource[i];
                                      NSString *final = tweetDictionary[@"profile_image_url"];
                                      NSLog(@"%@", final);
                                      }

                                      [self.feedTableView reloadData];
                                  } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                      NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
                                  }];

    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
    }];
    //[self getTimeLine];

}



#pragma mark Table View Methods

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.twitterDataSource.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellID =  @"FeedCell3" ;

    FeedCell3 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[FeedCell3 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }


    cell.nameLabel.text = @"RileyVLloyd";


    cell.likeCountLabel.text = @"293 likes";
    cell.commentCountLabel.text = @"55 comments";

    //NSString* profileImageName = self.profileImage[indexPath.row%self.profileImage.count];
    cell.profileImageView.image = _profileImage;

    NSInteger idx = indexPath.row;
    NSDictionary *t = self.twitterDataSource[idx];

    cell.updateLabel.text = t[@"text"];

    cell.dateLabel.text = @"1 day ago";

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way to accomplish this would be to use the [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) API. The API asynchronously loads the image, so then you won't have to worry about loading due to the main thread being used for loading the images. Also, this API only requires a couple lines of code below to be added to your UITableViewCell method.

```
NSString *aURL = t[@"user"][@"profile_image_url"];
[cell.profileImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aURL]
              placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does crash because you're trying to get a value for the key `profile_image_url` on `username` which is a string, hence the exception `<__NSCFString ...> is not key value coding-compliant for the key profile_image_url`.

Let's assume that what you really want to do here is retrieving the images for each tweet author.

You have to iterate over the statuses and, for each of them, extract the `profile_image_url` and create a `UIImage` with it.

Comment: I changed "username" to "statuses" and replaced "CIImage" with "UIImage," but I'm now getting the "No known class method for selector 'imageWithContentsOfURL:'" error again.

Comment: Statuses is an array, so you have to iterate over the array. Each element of this array is a dictionary, in which you can retrieve a value for the `profile_image_url` key.

Comment: Updated my code, It returns 1, Null, 2, then crashes with the following error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'